# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-2.7

Using Ubuntu, am trying to use the scikit-learn examples with this snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""" Examples of reading texts files and classifying them
"""
from __future__ import division
import datetime
import sklearn.datasets

time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
##from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
######## Reading text files
rootPath = r"/Home/web2py/corpus/20news-18828/"
```

However, I got this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/datasets/base.py", line 201, in load_files
    folders = [f for f in sorted(listdir(container_path))
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Home/web2py/corpus/20news-18828/
```

I am ery new to Ubuntu and scikit-learn stuff. What could be the issue/error and how do I get it solved.?

Comment: There is no 16.06.  Do you mean 16.04?

Comment: I suspect the rootPath should be "~/web2py/corpus/20news-18828/" but I am not using your "scikit-learn stuff".

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, thanks a lot. I used r"/Home/web2py/corpus/20news-18828/" instead of just  "/Home/web2py/corpus/20news-18828/".

Comment: @Thomas, yes am using 16.04. Thanks you

Comment: @wakamdr are you saying it's working now using `~/web2py/corpus/20news-18828/`? If so I can add an answer which you accept as solution, or you can simply delete the question. That way it doesn't stay as an "unanswered" question.

Comment: `/Home/...` what is that suppose to be?

Answer (score 6):

```
 OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Home/web2py/corpus/20news-18828/
```

> I am ery new to Ubuntu and scikit-learn stuff. What could be the issue/error and how do I get it solved.?

I see an error here if this is meant to be your home directory:`/Home/`. It should be `/home/`. Linux cares about both small and capital letters. We do not discriminate against letters as some other operating systems do ( :) )